# Composite Key trigger operation

Tags: triggers, key, new-operator, composite

3 weeks into school and 1 week into sql...

Essentially I have a problem, I think I know what I need to do, but I am having trouble sticking the landing.

For the business case, I have a weak entity consisting of 3 FK's and a date. I need to create a trigger or check where if someone tries to insert a row where 3/3 Fk's match, the existing row with the older date will drop and it will keep the newer one. I believe it should trigger the DELETE action AFTER insert on table, but I'm struggling to set up the condition.

Can I actually call on the composite key as a whole in this situation? Im not sure how to refer to the rows really in this situation.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

When you trigger the `DELETE` after performing the `INSERT`, you have to be careful not to delete the freshly-inserted row.

Instead, I'd delete any old rows `BEFORE INSERT`, like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrig BEFORE INSERT ON tbl BEGIN
  DELETE FROM tbl WHERE (id1,id2,id3)=(NEW.id1,NEW.id2,NEW.id3) AND mydate <= NEW.mydate;
END;
```

This way, you delete all rows that have

1. a matching triple of foreign keys, and
2. a date that is older (or as old) as the date of the to-be-inserted row.